# What is the deficiency in my Thailand ginger plant?

Tags: root-vegetables, ginger

My gala Thailand ginger is 3 months old, but the leaves are very pale yellow and the growth seems to be stunted. Please let me know if there is any deficiency.

Comment: We need a photo, or a very good description. How much do you water it? (overwatering is also a problem). What soil? (in a pot?) Fertilizers?

Comment: What kind of light conditions do you keep it in?